# correct class inheritance

Tags: python

I've written some code that allows the term 'job' to be used universally to perform a unique task. The specific jobs can be chosen through setting an initial variable "job_type". From that initial variable a particulay subclass is chosen to perform the appropriate job. Maybe the code will make more sense :)

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    # these variables would normally be called in from a config file
    job_type = 'job1'
    uni_var = 10

    job_select = superClass(job_type, uni_var)
    job_select.job()        


class superClass(object):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        self.job_type = job_type   
        self.uni_var = uni_var

        if self.job_type == 'job1':
            self.jobChoice = option1()
        else:
            self.jobChoice = option2()

    # This is the definition called by the main function it then
    # redirects the request to the appropriate job sub class   
    def job(self):
        self.jobChoice.job()

class option1(superClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 1'
        print uni_var

class option2(superClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 2'
        print uni_var
```

The thought behind this code was to allow a single/constant 'main' function, to action a variety of unique tasks based purely on the variable 'job_type'. Which it seems to be doing fine.

My question (as a very inexperienced coder) is, have I gone about this the right way or is there a better way to do things?

Also, have I set up the variable 'uni_var' correctly in the superClass to be correctly shared across all/any superClass subclasses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you really want is to use the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) here.

You could change your code to something like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    # these variables would normally be called in from a config file
    job_type = 'job1'
    uni_var = 10

    job_select = superClass.optionFactory(job_type, uni_var)
    job_select.job()        


class superClass(object):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        self.job_type = job_type   
        self.uni_var = uni_var

    # This is the definition called by the main function it then
    # redirects the request to the appropriate job sub class   
    def job(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @staticmethod
    def optionFactory(job_type, uni_var):
        "Return an instance of superClass based on job_type and uni_var."
        if job_type == "job1":
            return option1(job_type, uni_var)
        else:
            return option2(job_type, uni_var)

class option1(superClass):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        super(option1, self).__init__(job_type, uni_var)

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 1'
        print uni_var

class option2(superClass):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        super(option2, self).__init__(job_type, uni_var)

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 2'
        print uni_var
```

However, notice that this implementation will require that `superClass` be changed every time a new subclass is created. Another alternative would be to make the `optionFactory` method a standalone function (rather than a method of `superClass`). Like this:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    # these variables would normally be called in from a config file
    job_type = 'job1'
    uni_var = 10

    job_select = optionFactory(job_type, uni_var)
    job_select.job()        


class superClass(object):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        self.job_type = job_type   
        self.uni_var = uni_var

    # This is the definition called by the main function it then
    # redirects the request to the appropriate job sub class   
    def job(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class option1(superClass):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        super(option1, self).__init__(job_type, uni_var)

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 1'
        print uni_var

class option2(superClass):
    def __init__(self, job_type, uni_var):
        super(option2, self).__init__(job_type, uni_var)

    def job(self):
        print 'job option 2'
        print uni_var

def optionFactory(job_type, uni_var):
    "Return an instance of superClass based on job_type and uni_var."
    if job_type == "job1":
        return option1(job_type, uni_var)
    else:
        return option2(job_type, uni_var)
```

Comment: You can make this even simpler; if **all** your `__init__` methods do is call `super(...).__init__` with the same arguments you can just skip implementing `__init__` altogether and just inherit it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. That is pretty much all that happens, the same arguements (there are quite a few more than 2 though) will be used across all sub classes. How do I skip implementing __init__ and just inherit the arguements?

Comment: @user788462 Just don't write `__init__` methods in the subclasses at all, then they will automatically use the superclass `__init__`.

Comment: @user788462 P.S. if you want to address a comment to someone other than the person who wrote the answer, you should add `@pesonname` to your comment (e.g. `@Ben` to address it to me). That way StackOverflow nags them to come back and reply; it was only an accident that I actually looked at this comment and saw your question.

Comment: @Ben - Thanks again and for the heads up on how to particularly address someone. Just removing the __init__ certainly makes sense and is as easy as I thought it should be; in the confusion of trying everything else I must have missed the easiest option :(. So if I just use the optionFactory def (which pretty much just redirects the code, please correct me if I'm wrong) and remove all the sub class __init__, when they sub classes are called from main with the arguements it will automatically be pushed back to the superClass's __init__ to match up the arguements and make and instance of that???

Comment: @user788462 Pretty much right, yeah. Whenever you call a method (any method, not just `__init__`), if the class doesn't actually define that method it goes looking for one defined in a superclass. Though using `optionFactory` isn't quite just pulling your old code out of `superClass.__init__`, though. The big difference is that your original code resulted in a class instance that **contains** an instance of one of the two subclasses, while using optionFactory results in a class instance that **is** an instance of one of the two subclasses. Do you see why that is, and what the difference is?

Comment: @Ben Yep, I think I understand; I originally made an instance of a class from within an instance of another class, kind of returning an instance in an instance to main, which does sound quite messy when you put it like that. As opposed to making a single instance of the relevant class and just allowing the internal Python process to pull the required arguements from the superClass. I can imaging continuing down my original path would lead to some very hard to maintain and fault find code. Are there other issues that can arise from instances in instances?

Comment: @user788462 Oh, putting instances within other instances is quite common, it just wasn't a good fit for your use case. I say that because you didn't really need the outer instance and you had to write code that basically just did what Python would do on its own if you just used inheritance and method overriding. Glad you're on top of it now though!

Comment: @Ben In addition, regarding the uni_var variable shown in the second example from srgerg (exclude the sub class __init__). How is uni_var acquiring it's value in "class option1" and "class option2" "job()" definition, as it has not been defined internally by a self statement. Is it still printing it as a global variable (defined in main) or is it getting its value passed to it from the job_select.job() call in main?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4995/discussion-between-ben-and-user788462)

Comment: @srgerg Thanks again for your explaination.I went with your first example and made the factory a static method. Just a quick question regarding the NotImplementedError. What does it actually do? I read the python text "exception NotImplementedError, This exception is derived from RuntimeError. In user defined base classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they require derived classes to override the method.", but I still don't get what it's actually doing. I removed it from the code and it didn't seem to make any difference to the operation of the code.

Comment: @user788462 The `job` method of `superClass` should never be called, it should always be overridden by a `job` method in a subclass. However, if there's a bug in the code and the `job` method of `superClass` is called then we'll want to know that this error has occurred. The standard approach is to raise an exception to indicate that a method that should never be called has, in fact, been called. The fact that nothing changed when you removed it from your code is a good sign, but personally I'd leave it in there just in case there's a bug in your code somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a class as a factory, it's silly. You just need a consistent interface across implementations.

```
class JobA(object):
    def do_job(self, arg):
        print 'job a', arg

class JobB(object):
    def do_job(self, arg):
        print 'job b', arg

job_types = {
    'job1': JobA, 'job2': JobB
}

job_type = 'job1'
uni_var  = 10

job = job_types[job_type]()
job.do_job(uni_var)
```

Hell, if the jobs don't keep state, they shouldn't be classes, either, but functions instead.

```
def job_a(arg):
   ...

def job_b(arg):
   ...

job = job_types[job_type]
job(uni_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not using inheritance at all in your original code, and your code contains a severe bug, but masks it from appearing.

You create an instance of `superClass`, which stores `job_type` and `uni_var`, and then instantiates either `option1` or `option2` and stores a reference to that. The "subclasses" are initialised with no data (so they have no `job_type` or `uni_var` attributes, and you have to override `__init__` to do-nothing methods to avoid error).

When you call `job_select.job(...)`, `superClass` explicitly delegates to its `job_choice` attribute. So there's no useful inheritance going on; you've overridden everything about `superClass` in your subclasses, and instead having `job_select` be an instance of different sub-classes depending on the `job_type` and using method resolution to call the right code, `job_select` is always a `superClass` which contains an `option1` or `option2` and explicitly delegates to it.

The serious bug I mentioned: neither `option1` nor `option2` actually contains any information about the job, so their `job` methods can't do anything interesting. You call `print uni_var`, which doesn't work (it would normally be `print self.uni_var` to get the `uni_var` of this job), but **seems to work** because you have a global called `uni_var`. As soon as you start doing anything more complicated this scheme will fall over badly.

@srgerg's answer is a good example of what you could do to actually use inheritance and factory functions to solve your problem. @CatPlusPlus's answer is a good example of how you can use more appropriate tools for the very simple code in this example (may not be what you need if your real requirements are more complex what you've got written at the moment).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination and suggestions, I had feared as much. The actualy code is considerable more complicated with a number of definitions in each of the subclasses so I think adopting the Factory Method is probably preferable, though I currently know nothing about the Factor Method or using super(), so I'll read up on those. Thank you all for your help.